# How do you modify an iterator within a function?

Tags: c++

Suppose we have:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
using namespace std;

typedef map<int,int>::iterator it;

void some_func(it the_iterator)
{
   the_iterator->second += 1; //I want this value to change in main()
}

int main()
{
   //construct/populate map here

   for(it the_iterator = my_map.begin(); the_iterator != my_map.end(); the_iterator++)
   {
      some_func(the_iterator);
   }
}
```

I'm essentially trying to change the map value in the function by passing the iterator by reference, but I'm uncertain how to do this given that iterators are a little trickier to work with. Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: @remyabel was right, this is not changing the iterator. Please reword the question title

Comment: After the change from `->first` to `->second`, your code works. So what's the question?

Comment: There's no need to pass the iterator by reference? Why is that?

Comment: @user3064097: because you aren't modifying the iterator, you're modifying something (a container element) that the iterator tells you how to access. A copy of the iterator will tell you how to access the same thing that the original tells you how to access.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that turns out not to exist.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that your code is passing the integrator `by value`.

To pass it `by reference`, your variable type needs to be a reference:

`void some_func(it & the_iterator )`

That `&` is the key.

Comment: No, there's no need to pass the iterator by reference. The OP wants to increment the value in the (key, value) pair pointed to by the iterator by 1. The code posted works as is.

Comment: No, that doesn't need a reference.